# Find table with only two rows. Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm looking for a query that I can use in MS Access 2016 which will give me all Company ID's that have the values `"Iphone"` and `"Ipad"`. So all `CompanyID` that has only two rows with specific values.

```
CompanyID   Product_Name
1           Iphone
1           Ipad
1           Headphones
2           Iphone
2           Galaxy
3           Playstation 4
3           Nintendo Switch
4           Iphone
4           Ipad
```

In the example table above I will therefore get the `CompanyID = 4`.

I have tried to use the same logic as in SQL from the this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198666/select-rows-from-table-having-two-specific-values) but Access doesn't allow syntax `USING`.
The SQL query used in post is:

```
SELECT CompanyID
FROM DATA AS a
  JOIN DATA AS b
  USING (CompanyID)
WHERE a.Product_Name = "Iphone"
  AND b.Product_Name = "Ipad";
```

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you state:

> So all `CompanyID` that has **only two rows with specific values**... In the
>   example table above I will therefore get the **`CompanyID = 4`**.

It would seem that you require the `CompanyID` for which the only two `Product_Name` values are `Ipad` & `Iphone`, **with no other values** associated with the `CompanyID`.

To obtain this result, I might suggest the following SQL query:

```sql
select t.companyid
from data t
group by t.companyid
having max(t.product_name in ('Iphone','Ipad'))=-1
```

Which will return:

```
CompanyID
4
```

Here, for every record within each group of records associated with a given `CompanyID`, the expression `t.product_name in ('Iphone','Ipad')` is evaluated.

This expression will either return True (`-1`) or False (`0`).

If **all** records within the group are either `'Iphone'` or `'Ipad'`, then this expression will return True (`-1`) for every record, and the maximum over the group will be `-1`.

Whereas, if **any** record within the group is some other value, this expression will return False (`0`) and therefore the maximum of the group will be `0`, thus excluding it from the result.

Comment: This is actually more what I intended to achieve since I only get the relevant values and don't need to do extra filtering. Thanks for providing this answer. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` to filter the results that do not contain both values:

```
SELECT  a.CompanyID
  FROM  (
        SELECT  CompanyID
          FROM  DATA
          WHERE Product_Name = 'IPhone'
        ) a
    INNER JOIN (
               SELECT  CompanyID
                 FROM  DATA
                 WHERE Product_Name = 'Ipad'
               ) b ON b.CompanyID = a.CompanyID
```

Output:

```
CompanyID
1
4
```

**How does this work?**

Firstly all results that have an `IPhone` are gathered.  Then this is joined with all results that have an `IPad`.  Only results with both rows matching (because of the `INNER JOIN`) will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

While late to this, it looks like they're only being pulled from one table - DATA. If that's the case then the easiest solution should just be

```
SELECT DATA.CompanyID
FROM (DATA)
WHERE DATA.Product_Name = "Iphone"
  AND DATA.Product_Name = "Ipad";
```

For Access, the FROM statement is generally only used for combining tables, or queries, and the data manipulation is in the other statements.

If there's more than one table and the connection between the two tables is CompanyID, then it should look more like this;

```
SELECT DATA1.CompanyID
FROM (DATA1 INNER JOIN DATA1.CompanyID ON DATA2.CompanyID) 
WHERE DATA2.Product_Name = "Iphone"
  AND DATA2.Product_Name = "Ipad";
```